# can we point o an animal and "what animal is this ? or which animal is this? which one is correct?

Tags: questions, format

I just wanted to know if its gramatically correct to say what animal is this? or which animal I this?

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct to ask either

> "What animal is this?" or 
>   "Which animal is this?"

Generally, while teaching children, for instance, if you hold up a picture of an elephant, you would probably want to ask,

> "What animal is this?"

If you had a poster of various mammals and pointed to each of them, you could use both constructions, such as

> "What animal is this?"

And then, pointing to another,

> "Which animal is this?"